# Shortcut to batch file cannot be pinned to Win10 Start menu

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, start-menu

Right-click on the batch file shortcut (as well as batch file itself). Context menu doesn't contain "Pin to Start" command. Is there any way to pin batch file to Windows 10 start menu?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

After you create the shortcut go to Properties and in the Target field add `cmd /c "path"`, then you can pin it by right clicking on the shortcut and selecting Pin ...

[image]

Comment: On my system, after I create the shortcut, I don't see "Pin to Taskbar." But I do see "Pin to Start." I can select that and then right-click on it in the Start panel, and in "More >" there is "Pin to Taskbar."

Comment: upvoted as this works. Can you explain how to pin to taskbar?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid You should also have "Pin to taskbar" in the right click menu.

Comment: As for June 2023 - this does not work in the current windows 10 release. 
Artfaith answer below is the correct one.

Answer (score 12):

1. Create a directory in
   `%appdata%/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/` (e.g. Custom);
2. Create a shortcut to a batch/executable/target in the directory;
   2.1. (Optional) Wait for 5-20 seconds so the OS could handle the changes;
3. Open `Start Menu`;
4. Search for the shortcut using Start Menu;
5. Right click on the result and press `Pin to Start`.

Answer (score 1):

Update:
I used the suggestion above and Windows 10 force modified my path to
 C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c" C:\pathto\batch.bat". 
This works for me.

Comment: Could you add the name of the contributor you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Create the shortcut file in a folder other than Programs. Then copy/move that shortcut into the Programs folder. You may need to provide admin credentials, but it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

This answer provides additional details to the solutions by [@User552853](https://superuser.com/users/552853/user552853) and [@Angel](https://superuser.com/users/570332/angel) and a workaround when updates are needed.

The solution by [@User552853](https://superuser.com/users/552853/user552853) ends up copying the shortcut to `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`, meaning that the `Start Menu` link is different than the original shortcut created in the answer. This is important to keep in mind because updates to the original shortcut won't be reflected when the `Start Menu` shortcut is clicked. My workaround is:

1. Delete the `Start Menu` shortcut
2. Right click on the original (but modified) shortcut and select `Pin to Start`

Pinning to taskbar works in a similar but copies the shortcut to a different folder.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).