# Is it possible to have multiple shortcuts of windows cmd in the start menu?

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, start-menu

In windows 10, I would like to pin multiple shortcuts of cmd.exe to the start to have them execute different preset commands in different folders.

However, when I add a second, differently configured shortcut to the start menu folder, it replaces the tile of the previous one - just the tile, both shortcuts are still in the start menu folder - this does not seem right.

Comment: My recommendation would be to create the various shortcuts on your desktop and utilize different names (with an appropriate suffix) for each one.  Once you have created them, right-click each one and select `Pin to Start`.

Comment: This doesn't work: I don't have the option `Pin to Start`, but only `unpin from start` in these new shortcuts

Comment: First of all, unpin all of the CMD shortcuts that currently reside on your Start Menu. Next, click on the Start button, search for CMD and in the result that says Command Prompt, right-click and select `Open file location`.  In the subsequent window, right-click the Command Prompt shortcut, select Copy, and then paste it to your desktop. Paste additional copies, as necessary. Modify the properties of the target within each one, apply the changes, and rename each shortcut accordingly. Finally, right-click each shortcut and select `Pin to Start`.

Comment: work is crazy at the moment, I will reply in the next couple of days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's folder that can contain anything that any other folder can contain.

It sounds like you are talking about batch files. You can make batch files for all the things you want the shortcuts to do and put those in your start menu.

ADDITIONAL READING:
http://www.trytoprogram.com/batch-file/

Comment: together with https://superuser.com/questions/1289948/shortcut-to-batch-file-cannot-be-pinned-to-win10-start-menu and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957076/keep-cmd-open-after-bat-file-executes this is an ok workaround for me, and has the benefit of being able to store the batch files for future use, e.g. when the system is being set up again. 
still, I think it's odd that I cannot to this directly with the cmd shortcuts