# Windows 10 move .bat shortcut to task bar

Tags: windows-10, evil

I want to be able to launch a .bat file I've written from the task bar.

I've successfully created the shortcut and have located it in Explorer. However, Windows doesn't do anything when I drag the shortcut to the task bar, and it doesn't display "task bar" as a destination in the "Send To" menu.

Is this a new restriction, or is it possible to have a bat launcher on the task bar?

Steps to reproduce:

- Create a .bat file on the desktop (contents don't matter).
- Create a shortcut to that .bat file.
- Try to drag the shortcut to the task bar from Explorer.
- Right-click the shortcut and look in vain for some way of making it launchable from the task bar.
- `GIVE UP`

OS: Windows 10 Pro

Comment: [This SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1289948/shortcut-to-batch-file-cannot-be-pinned-to-win10-start-menu) has your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Right click on the Desktop
- Pick the command "New -> Shortcut" from the context menu
- In the shortcut target, enter `cmd /c "full path to your batch file`"
- Name the shortcut
- Right click that new shortcut
- Choose "Pin to Task Bar" from the context menu.